# Twitter の「検索結果に対応するツイート一覧」を React に埋め込む方法

Tags: html, css, reactjs, api, twitter

お世話になります。
Twitter の検索結果に対応するツイート一覧を、できるだけ快適に React に埋め込みたいと思っているのですが、良い方法をご存じの方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

動作のイメージとしては、Twitter で hoge と検索した場合に、 https://twitter.com/search?q=hoge に対応する検索結果が描画されることを期待しています。
類似する機能だと、[react-twitter-embed](https://saurabhnemade.github.io/react-twitter-embed/?path=/story/twitter-timeline-embed--timeline-likes-with-user-id) という React のライブラリを使うことで特定のアカウントやidに紐づけられたタイムラインを取得することが可能です。見た目が良く使い勝手も良さそうなのですが、検索結果を表示する機能がサポートされていません。検索結果に対応するツイートを取得すること自体は Twitter API を用いることで可能ですが、取得できるのはあくまでテキストなので、見た目を成型する手間が生じます。react-twitter-embed では「いいね」ボタンのようなテキスト以外の情報も簡単に埋め込むことができることを考えると、自前で成型せずにうまく埋め込める方法があるのではないかと考えています。

良い方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃれば、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

react-twitter-embed の TwitterTimelineEmbed は、Twitter が提供する embed script、具体的には https://publish.twitter.com などから参照できる [widgets.js](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/overview) を使っています。一方で widgets.js は任意の文字列に対する検索に対応していません。2018 年に[廃止されました](https://twittercommunity.com/t/embed-live-search-results-for/103705/4)。

このため、私が知る限り、API を使って検索結果を持ってきて自前で表示するのが正攻法のはず……です。